# I have one entity, i need to add property of entity type

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, ef-code-first-mapping

```
**public class Ticket : BaseEntity
    {       
        public TicketType TicketType { get; set; } 
    }
public class TicketType : AuxiliaryInfoBaseEntity
    {     
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }**
```

*In Ticket Entity i need one property of TicketType and type of column should be byte in Ticket. 
Resulting table will look like.Table-Ticket:column TicketType(tinyint,not null).
When i trying to migrate, i am getting this exception.
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Ticket.TicketType' is of type 'TicketType' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
Please help me with some soluntion thanks.*

Comment: Could you share what is your `BaseEntity` and `AuxiliaryInfoBaseEntity` and your DbContext?

Comment: public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        static BaseEntity()
        {
            Triggers<BaseEntity>.Inserting += entry =>
            {
                entry.Entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entry.Entity.IsDeleted = false;
                entry.Entity.IsActive = true;
            };
            Triggers<BaseEntity>.Deleting += entry =>
            {
                entry.Entity.DeletedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entry.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                entry.Cancel = true;
            }

Comment: This is base entity

Comment: AuxiliaryInfoBaseEntity
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
      
        public AuxiliaryInfoBaseEntity()
        {
            Triggers<AuxiliaryInfoBaseEntity>.Inserting += entity =>
            {
                entity.Entity.IsActive = true;
            };
        }
    }

Comment: class WriteOnlyContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }       
        public WriteOnlyContext(DbContextOptions<WriteOnlyContext> options)
               : base(options) { }
        public WriteOnlyContext()
               : base() { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
           dbconnection   
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating (builder);
            builder.ConfigureTicket ();
        }
    }